# How do I make bootstrap work in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to install this application: https://github.com/dilshanraja/Texas-holdem

But there is very little help in the ReadMe

The error I'm currently stuck on is:

```html
ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap'
  (in /home/tony/Texas-holdem/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:13)):
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Poker - Have fun while you lose your money!</title>
    5:   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    6:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
    7:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    8:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    9: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___4142171802834991719_70121515696740'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:11:in `angular'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the simplest way to add bootstrap is using the gem for it. The gem will put bootstrap resources into rails assets pipeline, but you must add some lines to include its resources on application.css and application.js

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem

Answer (score 0):

The next time I went into the IDE (Rubymine) to look at this Rubymine detected that [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) needed installing. After the successful install of npm I just needed to install MongoDB and the application worked.